# Adding Borders to individual items of a LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm trying to use border around each **item** of the **longlistselector** to distinguishing individual **items**. I tried adding **BorderThickness** property to my **longlistselector** but it didn't give any borders around my list items.

Here is my xaml file

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>    
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="lls_Text_SelectionList" ItemsSource="{Binding }" FontSize="36" Margin="0,10,0,88" HideEmptyGroups="True"  Background="Gray" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="10" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've used various values for **BorderThickness** and **BorderBrush** but its gives me no border. Can any one assist me in solving this problem??

Comment: are you using any kind of ItemTemplate for LongListSelector ?

Comment: No, I'm not using any templates.

Comment: no Templates? really?

Comment: No I'm not using any...

Comment: @prince Than how could you show list of items ??

Comment: I'm new to .NET, I don't know about templates. Whatever code I'm using  for creating list I've shown it in my question and for adding items to the list I'm using DataContext at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ItemTemplate. Something like this:

```
<phone:LongListSelector HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="lls_Text_SelectionList" ItemsSource="{Binding }" " Margin="0,10,0,88" HideEmptyGroups="True"  Background="Gray" >   
  <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="10">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```